# Rake aborted, Error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm following 'Getting Started with Ruby on Heroku', but when attempting to run the demo app locally with

```
$ bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
```

I get

```
sam@samoliver:~/ruby-getting-started$ bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
/home/sam/ruby-getting-started/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/ruby-getting-started/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/sam/ruby-getting-started/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/uglifier-2.5.3/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/uglifier-2.5.3/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.0/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
/home/sam/ruby-getting-started/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/ruby-getting-started/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/sam/ruby-getting-started/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
sam@samoliver:~/ruby-getting-started$
```

I tried removing and adding 'uglifier' (2.5.3) again to no effect and I do have 'therubyracer'  installed, so I don't understand what is ExecJS complaining about.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'puma'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Try install node.js. In Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install nodejs

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I got another error now, will try to figure out. Would you know why nodejs solved it, while therubyracer didn't?

Comment: I think therubyracer doesn't install any JS runtime.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks again!

Comment: I had the same problem on an EC2 Ubuntu instance just today.  Thanks for the answer @AlexanderShlenchack!

Comment: Uncomment: `gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby`

Comment: @SamOliver That fixed it for me! You should maybe put it in as an answer so I could upvote it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

***install nodejs***

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 11):

uncomment the line below in Gemfile

```
#gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

run in the terminal

```
bundle install
```

Comment: This one helped on FreeBSD, the accepted answer didn't!

Comment: @DenisMysenko I also use FreeBSD. I always need to use `therubyracer` in my Gemfile to make rails work. Even though I have `node` installed. How did you do it? Any PATH set in the application config?

Answer (score 1):

Uglifier is JavaScript compressor, so it need javascript runtime try installing `nodejs`

Run this to install NodeJS in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

or

```
brew install nodejs
```

if you are on a OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I had to go into my root folder (on ubuntu use

```
sudo su)
```

From there use `apt-get install nodejs`, then exit the root and run `bundle install` then you should be able to run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gem update --system 1.4.2
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding some descriptive information about what the command does and why it will help.  Were you able to reproduce the OP's issue and did this fix it?