# Ruby on rails uglifier error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uglifier

On windows and yes, node.js is installed.

I just installed ruby on rails following a video tutorial but when I go to run rails server I get this error:

```
c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from c:/row/dev/Hello_World/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

my gemfile does have uglifier in it uglifier is installed, and the bundle install shows uglifier being used.

What might the issue be?

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer. It is the same as yours. It might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294450/devise-gives-error-while-running-deviseinstall-in-rails-application

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have JS runtime installed which uglifier need for.
You may install nodejs.

That way for doing that on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: nodejs is installed and working as far as I can tell. Is there a way to confirm?

Comment: @mike just type `node -v` in console. If will show you a version if it's installed.

Comment: @Mike could you then try to use rubyracer adding that to your gemfile `gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby` and running bundle install. It may help. Let's see what it will give.

Comment: I got a tip on a previous question that therubyracer doesn't work on windows.