# Ruby on Rails. gem error cant find installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

When I run `rails server` I get this error.

```
rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'
```

Then, I install it:

```
gem install uglifier
Successfully installed uglifier-2.7.2
...
```

But I still get the same error. What could it be? I'm using rvm and I'm new to Rails...

Comment: did you run `bundle install`? Are there any errors?

Comment: Do you need to install node.js? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269101/rake-aborted-error-while-trying-to-load-the-gem-uglifier

Comment: @Tim That solved it. Thanks a lot!. If you you could write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: :) Cool, glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to install node js as there is a dependency on the run time, that helpfully does not show up.

Please find a link: [Rake aborted, Error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269101/rake-aborted-error-while-trying-to-load-the-gem-uglifier)

where they suggest apt-get install nodejs